# Groovy: Send a request to a URL, ignoring the result

Tags: java, groovy

In groovy, is there a way to send a request to a URL, ignoring the response? The main aim is to send more requests to the server, in a shorter period of time.

As the result is unimportant to me, once the request is sent, I don't want the script to wait for a response before continuing.

Here's my current script:

```
(1..50).each { element->
  def url = "http://someUrl"
  url.toURL().text 
}
```

In this code, the `text` method has to load the entire response, which I don't really care about.  The important part is that the request is sent, and waiting for a response is unimportant.

Is there a similar `send` method? (along the lines of..

```
url.toURL().send
```

Alternatively, is there a "groovy" way I can speed this up using GPARS to run the loop in parallel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For just sending the URL, you could just use the `withInputStream` or `withReader` methods to send the request without reading the text.  This will just create a handler to read the incoming text that would immediately close.

As for GPars, you can just use a combination of `withPool` and `callAysnc` to create a thread pool to execute the requests concurrently.  For example:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='0.12')
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsExecutorsPool.withPool

withPool(50) {
    50.times {
        Closure callUrl = {"http://google.com".toURL().withReader {}}
        callUrl.callAsync();
    }
}
```

However, if you're not concerned with the number of threads, you could just create your own threads without GPars.  For example:

```
50.times { 
    Closure callUrl = {"http://google.com".toURL().withReader {}}
    Thread.start callUrl
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but won't that potentially leave 50 open connections?  Wouldn't `Closure callUrl = {"http://google.com".toURL().withReader {} }` be better, as it closes the connection as well?

Comment: Excellent point Tim.  I've changed my examples accordingly.  Though in this case, since there were no outstanding references to the `Reader` object, the connection would have been closed when the object was GCed.  However, that could have the potential to keep a lot of connections open until the JVM decided to collect those objects.